# Can the Ocumetic bionic lens give flawless vision?

Tags: medical-science, ophthalmology

[Ocumetics](http://ocumetics.com/index.html) claim to have developed a bionic lens that can be surgically implanted into the eye to restore clear focus to patients.

> For a half century, ophthalmic surgeons have envisioned an intraocular lens capable of restoring eyesight at all distances. Ocumetics™ Technology Corporation was founded to achieve this goal. Employing state-of-the art materials and production techniques, Ocumetics™ Technology Corporation is in the process of developing a highly advanced intraocular lens, one that is capable of restoring clear vision at all distances, without glasses or contact lenses, and without the visual quality problems that have plagued current accommodative and multifocal intraocular lens designs.
>
> [...]
>
> Cataract surgery is the most common and successful procedure in medicine. The Bionic Lens™ is currently undergoing clinical testing with the ultimate goal of clinical approval. Ophthalmic surgeons, utilizing standard surgical techniques, augmented by the accuracy of femtosecond lasers and adjunct intraocular techniques, will then be able to implant the the Bionic Lens™  to help patients achieve their visual goals.

[Higher Perspectives](http://www.higherperspectives.com/superhuman-vision-1568738067.html?utm_source=cleo&utm_content=inf_10_34_2&tse_id=INF_2b54ac431b624851b5668fd39e897a41)

> In an incredible feat of modern science and medicine, a new bionic lens for the eye currently in development would give humans 3x 20/20 vision at any age. Called Ocumetics Bionic Lens, the lens was developed by Dr. Garth Webb, an optometrist from British Columbia, Canada, who sought a way to optimize eyesight.

With this lens, patients would have flawless vision. No more glasses for driving or reading and no more invasive contact lenses either. Glasses will one day be a thing of the past.

Ever since I heard about Ocumetric's founder, Dr. Garth Webb, and this product, I've been eager to hear more, but I haven't heard substantial. Occasionally I'll come across some discussion online that has unsourced comments that ophthalmologists don't think the results of his studies are legitimate.

Is there experimental data to demonstrate that these claims are realistic?

Comment: "currently undergoing clinical testing" ... so you expect us to find the answer before they do?  My guess (based on having received "bionic" lenses because of cataracts) is that it should be possible.

Comment: @GEdgar I thought that maybe there was a journal somewhere where other reputable ophthalmologists had maybe discussed the procedure. If it's impossible to answer just vote close

Comment: Too low rep for voting close...

Comment: You can flag too

Comment: If your primary vision problem is caused by cataracts or other lens-related things then you can certainly get better vision by installing a new lens. But many eye problems are caused by issues elsewhere in the eye so it can't help. The claims seem to gloss over this issue.